# Editing an already existing text file

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to edit an existing file that I had just created and so far I have no clue on how it's done.

Can anyone show me how and please explain line by line on what the code does?

```
import java.io.*;

public class Hey {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("Title");
        String title = br.readLine();
        File f = new File(title +".txt");
        f.createNewFile();
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        System.out.println("What you want to input in the text");
        String text = br.readLine();
        bw.write(text);
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();


    }
}
```

Comment: 1. This code has resource leaks and there is no proper exception handling (other than to simply throw a generic exception to the caller which is *bad* - particularly inside a main()-method). 2. Your title suggests you want to *edit an already existing file*. How does that go together with `f.createNewFile();` in your snippet above?

Comment: ... Currently your code will simply overwrite all the contents of your target file if it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

Creates a read buffer from the standard input.

```
String title = br.readLine();
```

Reads from this buffer until there's a return character sequence found ('\n', '\r' or "\r\n"). The entire line excluding the return sequence will be saved as `title`.

```
 File f = new File(title +".txt");
```

Creates a File object with the name read from the console.

```
f.createNewFile();
```

Creates the file if it doesn't exist yet.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
```

Creates a buffered writer to write into `fw`.

```
String text = br.readLine();
```

Again reads a line from the console.

```
 bw.write(text);
```

Writes this line into the buffer.

```
bw.flush();
```

Ensures the whole buffer is flushed into the file (written into the file).

```
bw.close();
```

Closes the buffer of your buffered writer. You should also close the reader buffer `br` and the FileWriter `fw`.